# Laravel insert not saving created_at, updated_at columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Calendar model. I want to insert mass data.

```
$data = [
   [
       'weekday' => 1,
       'status'  => 'active'
   ]
   .......
];
$calendar->insert($data)
```

but in db created_at, and updated_at is null Why??;

Comment: Because in order to have timestamps you need to use `save()`, not `insert()` which is method of query builder not of eloquent model.

Comment: In create array either pass them manually with set them to ``$fillable`` in model, or just update your migration script like ```$table->timestamp(’something_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));```

Comment: your laravel version please ?

Comment: laravel verion is 5.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you INSIST on using insert and to update timestamps automatically, Laravel does not offer this.

you need to do it manually from the code side.
as someone mention in some answer as:

```
'created_at' => $calendar->freshTimestamp(),
'updated_at' => $calendar->freshTimestamp()
```

I faced a similar problem in one project, so I wanted to insert but without adding the timestamps in my code every time I insert so.
if you need to use insert without adding the timestamps manually. you can change your migrations file and add the timestamps manuallay:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

now the database will handle the created at and updated at on insert.

the created_at will be equal to the updated_at and equal to the current timestamp

then on save() laravel will handle updating the updated_at

Answer (score 2):

Because you're inserting data, created_at and updated_at will only be automatically filled if you're using `->save()`.

Make sure you have added those fields to your `protected $fillable = [];` array.

You can also use `$calendar->update($data)` or

```
$calendar->fill($data);
$calendar->save();
```

Hope I understood your question.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is this

```
$data = [
   [
       'weekday' => 1,
       'status'  => 'active',
       'created_at' => $calendar->freshTimestamp(),
       'updated_at' => $calendar->freshTimestamp()
   ]
   .......
];
$calendar->insert($data)
```

2 solution In `Model`

```
/**
 *
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->created_at = $model->freshTimestamp();
        $model->updated_at = $model->freshTimestamp();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent expects created_at and updated_at columns to exist on your tables.

If you want that these columns automatically managed by Eloquent, set the  $timestamps property on your model to true and also add columns name into protected $fillable = []; array.

```
public $timestamps = true;
```

Comment: By default **$timestamps = true;** see trait **Illuminate\Support\Carbon\HasTimestamps**

Answer (score 0):

Use **YourModel::create($data)** instead of **YourModel::insert($data)**, create() will fill the created_at and updated_at fields automatically, It's work for me.

If it's not work add below code to the your model and try again

```
const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';
```